# ncurses installed... but won't compile code

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

I've recently returned to Xubuntu 22.04 after a brief stint on Fedora.
Under Fedora, I seemed to be able to install ncurses okay.
I could then simply write code and compile with commands like:

$gcc -lncurses main.c

Now, when I try that, it gives me:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczC1PpK.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `initscr'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `printw'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `stdscr'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `wgetch'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `endwin'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried installing using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev  libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
sudo apt-get install libncurses5 libncurses5:i386
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386
```

All appear to install well with no errors or warnings.

And yet, my code simply doesn't recognise the ncurses function.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>


int main()
{
    initscr();
    
    printw("Hello World!");
    getch();
    
    endwin();   
    return 0;
}
```

It's so simple, and yet it fails.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `gcc -lncurses main.c`

you need to use

```
gcc  main.c -lncurses
```

the -lncurses directive comes after your object code on the gcc command line

Comment: Ah! Okay!
That worked!
Funny... when I did it on Fedora, I did it the other way around (as per some online resources... can't remember what..) and it worked.

But, okay!
What works, works! 

Many thanks!

Comment: @Lincoln for a more thorough discussion see [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter)

Answer (score 0):

Try `gcc main.c  -lncurses` instead. As from man page,

> the placement of the -l option is significant.